# RSS feed integration with mySQL database structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rss

I have a topics table that has user generated topics and RSS generated topics but in the existing mySQL database setup, when the RSS feed is inserted into the database, the user generated topic fields are NULL (e.g. topic_title), and when a user adds a topic, the RSS fields in the topic table are NULL (e.g. rss_title and rss_source_name). I also have foriegn keys in the topic table which become NULL (e.g. user_id) when the RSS stream is pulled through - this causes data to fail inserting as user_id is a foriegn key and cannot be NULL. Ideally, I'd like both user generated topics and RSS topics to be stored in the topics table without the fields becoming null, but not sure what would be the best way to structure the existing database (below is an example):

- Category table

  - cat_id
- Topic table (Should store all both user generated topics and RSS generated topics)

  - topic_id
  - cat_id
  - topic_title (becomes NULL when RSS feed is inserted into database)
  - user_id (becomes NULL when RSS feed is inserted into database - this causes data to fail inserting as user_id is a foriegn key and cannot be NULL)
  - rss_title (becomes NULL when user creates content)
  - rss_source_name (becomes NULL when user creates content)
- Comments table

  - comments_id
  - topic_id
  - comments_title
  - user_id

Will the topics table have to be separated into two separate tables (one for user generated and one for RSS), but this would cause NULL issues in the comments table. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want those fields to be null, just declare them to be null! FK constraint checks in SQL treat a null FK as ok.

EDIT part 1 Since user and rss topics both shave titles, just have one field/column instead of two (one for user & one for rss).

If you don't ever want a field to be null then you have to put it in a separate table. Have a table for a user topic topic_id and user_id and another for an RSS topic topic_id and source_name. Then use a table for all topics with columns shared by both user and rss topics, eg topic_id, title, cat_id etc. Each of user and rss topic tables has a topic_id FK to the all topics table. This is standard table subtyping. There are topics, user topics and rss topics.

EDIT part 2 FKs are not columns or pointers. They are constraints. They say that columns' values always appear as other columns' values.

You don't say what the Comments table means. Apparently a user creates a comment, and there is a constraint that its topic_id be of either a user or rss topic_id? Now have a FK to the shared table.

EDIT part 3

Here are the (renamed for clarity) tables per above:

```
All_topics(topic_id,title,cat_id)
    pk (topic_id)
    fk (cat_id) references Category (cat_id)
User_topics(topic_id,user_id)
    pk (topic_id)
    fk (topic_id) references All_topics (topic_id)
Rss_topics(topic_id,source_name)
    pk (topic_id)
    fk (topic_id) references All_topics (topic_id)

Comments(comments_id,topic_id,comments_title,user_id)
    pk (comment_id)
    fk (topic_id) references All_topics (topic_id)
```

If a user_topic or rss_topic row is added or deleted then you add or delete the topic row with its topic_id (which also holds it title).

If you need to keep user/rss titles separate (why??) then there's no all-topic title and topic_title and rss_title go in the user and rss topic tables.

Ideally also some constraints. (Or certain different design styles for table subtyping.)

```
select topic_id from All_topics = select topic_id from User_topics UNION select topic_id from User_topics
NOT EXISTS (select topic_id from User_topics JOIN USING (topic_id) Rss_topics)
```

No nulls.

Comment: Creating a shared table will still result in null fields (either the users topics table will be set or the rss topics will be set). For now, I will keep everything in one table but is it ok for topic_title to be null when rss_title is filled in the same row? Topic_title is not a foriegn key - from the PHP side of things, I would then call both $rsstitle and $topictitle, and which ever column has data will be displayed

Comment: 1. There are no nulls in this design. The table for user topic_ids (only) has also only a user_id column, and this is never null. The table for rss topic_ids (only) has also a source name column and this is never null. I suspect you misunderstand. If you disagree, please edit declarations and a sequence of transactions  into your question to explain your needs. 2. Per my answer, null FK columns pass constraint checking. Non-constrained columns when null or not pass constraint checking. You seem to have some misconceptions about nulls and constraints.

Comment: From my understanding, the shared table will contain a null e.g. the shared topic table is connected to both the rss table and normal user generated table - if the topic is rss generated, then there would be a null on the FK for the user generated topic_id on the shared topic table. Anyways, I've decided that a single topic table approach would be best, but as for constraint checking, I'm assuming it's fine for topic_title / rss_title to be null (neither are FK)

Comment: Re shared table: FKs are not columns or pointers. There are no nulls. Re single table: I repeat FK null is fine. So why say "neither are FK"? See edited answer.